# Creating a subclass and object at the same time

Tags: c#, subclass

I am looking for a C# equivalent of a Java idiom.

In Java, if you have an abstract class, you cannot directly create an object of that class; you need to subclass it (and provide an override of the abstract methods) first. But you can actually create the subclass and object at the same time:

```
public abstract class Type {
  abstract Kind kind();
  public static final Type BOOLEAN =
      new Type() {
        @Override
        Kind kind() {
          return Kind.BOOLEAN;
        }
      };
```

The above doesn't translate verbatim into C#; is there an equivalent idiom? Or do you just need to write it out longhand, declaring a named subclass first, then creating an object of the subclass?

Comment: You need to write it out longhand and name the type in C# (although you can make it a private inner class to restrict its visibility). In fairness, the main utility for this pattern in Java is callbacks, and C# uses delegates for this, so you find yourself reaching for it far less often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Maybe you can try making a private class which implements your class `Type` and then make a method that returns that?

However, maybe take a look at what you're trying to implement. This might not be the right pattern for your problem.

```cs
public abstract class Type
{
    public abstract string Kind();

    public static Type BOOLEAN()
    {
        return new BooleanType();
    }

    private class BooleanType : Type
    {
        public override string Kind()
        {
            return "Boolean";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Note in C#, you'd probably use an abstract property there)